# Empty request.FILES in Django

Tags: python, django, forms, post

I'm trying to send a file via post request to server on localhost. I'm using HttpRequester in Firefox (also tried Postman in Chrome and Tasker on Android) to sumbit request.
The problem is that `request.FILES` is always empty. But when I try to print `request.body` it shows some non-human-readable data which particularly include the data from the file I want to upload (it's a database).  So it makes sense to me that somehow file arrives to the server.

From Django docs:

> Note that FILES will only contain data if the request method was POST
>   and the  that posted to the request had
>   enctype="multipart/form-data". Otherwise, FILES will be a blank
>   dictionary-like object.

There was an error *'Invalid boundary in multipart: None'* when I tried to set Content-type of request to 'multipart/form-data'. An error disappeared when I added ';boundary=frontier' to Content-type.

Another approach was to set enctype="multipart/form-data".

Therefore I have several questions:

1. Should I use exactly multipart/form-data content-type?
2. Where can I specify enctype? (headers, parameters, etc)
3. Why the file's data contains in request.body but request.FILES is empty?

Thanks

Comment: What is the solution?

Answer (score 3):

> 1. Should I use exactly multipart/form-data content-type?

Django supports only `multipart/form-data`, so you must use that content-type.

> 2. Where can I specify enctype? (headers, parameters, etc)

in normal HTML just put `enctype="multipart/form-data"` as one of parameters of your form element. In HttpRequester it's more complicated, because I think it lacks support for `multipart/form-data` by default. http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.2 is more details about `multipart/form-data`, it should be possible to run it in HttpRequester by hand.

> 3. Why the file's data contains in request.body but request.FILES is empty?

You've already answered that:

> > Note that FILES will only contain data if the request method was POST and the that posted to the request had enctype="multipart/form-data". **Otherwise, FILES will be a blank dictionary-like object.**